# LibreOfficeDev5.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 does not save modified forms

Tags: ubuntu, development, libreoffice-base

I've installed LO dev 5.3, because I need direct SQL to work, which I read was fixed in this version, but now I'm facing the issue that I can't edit any forms anymore.
I can create new forms using the wizard only.
These new forms as well, cannot be saved, 
even upon closing the form with a changed layout, 
it does so without confirmation, errors and ultimately without saving it.

It's funny that the save button indicates non-saved changes immediately on opening the form in edit mode.

Anyone ran in this before, maybe earlier dev versions ?

Edit:
I've installed also dev version 5.2, which suffers the same problem.
Perhaps a misconfiguration on my machine ?

Comment: I have also found many bugs in LibreOffice, and have not had good experiences reporting bugs.